# How to calculate interest based on interest rates by ArrayTable in java

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

I'm still very new for the java, and I'm now doing a Java program for calculating interest. I have all the data for interest rates, I use 2D array to store them, basically it looks like: 
`//2014{xxxx}//2013{xxxx},`

I need to use them to calculate the interest expenditure based on different months in different years. I have the maximum repayment years`MaxYr` and flatcost. The method below is just a rough idea but not a correct code.

```
public void SInterest()
{
    SRate = new ArrayList<SIBOR>();
    for (int k = 1; k <= MaxYr; k++ ){
        for (int r = 0; r < 20; r++){
            for (int c = 0; c < 12; c++ ){
                double SInterest = (calculateLoan(flatcost)) * SRate[r][c];
```

Since I am not familiar with arraytable method and hardly figure out by browsing online, hope someone could give me some hints， appreciate it.

Comment: You are not building a multidimensional array; SRate is a ArrayList and the method `get` should receive only one parameter. I highly recommend you to check this tutorial: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_arraylist_class.htm

Comment: @irrelephant Is it necessary for me to adopt arraytable for this program? Since the number of data is really big.

Comment: @PedroMoreira I have two parameters, raw is for different years, column is for different months

Comment: What the variable `SIBOR` represents? Is it an array? If yes you should use something like this `SRate.get(r)[c]`

Comment: @PedroMoreira It is the name of the class